# Google App Engine vote counting

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an App Engine Python App where players post their answers to questions and a team of judges vote them as right or wrong. Votes are cast by justices using this model:

```python
class vote(ndb.Model):
   judge = ndb.KeyProperty(justice)
   value = ndb.BooleanProperty()
   timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
   question = ndb.KeyProperty(game_has_question_has_player)
```

And questions have this structure:

```python
class game_has_question_has_player(ndb.Model):
   match = ndb.KeyProperty(game)
   challenge = ndb.KeyProperty(questionList)
   gamer = ndb.KeyProperty(player)
   answer = ndb.StringProperty()
   passed = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

As soon as the number of positive or negative votes accounts for 1/2 +1 of the judges the question is deemed as passed or failed. This can happen before all the judges have voted and is key to the App dealing the rest of the challenges to go on with the game.

My problem has to do with that moment. How can I know reliably when a challenge/question has just been passed? To summarize where I am stuck, this are the options I am able to see:

- The voting method queries previous votes and decides (taking into account the vote being cast) wether to update the "passed" field in "game_has_question_has_player". The problem here is that queries to count previous votes can give a wrong answer due to other votes being simultaneously cast by the rest of the judges and other counts being performed also simultaneously.
- I change the 'question' model to add a counter for the votes. I see a contention problem there as judges are notified simultaneously of the challenges to vote and can therefore vote very close in time to each other. I can use transactions, but I am not clear about it's limitations in production (I am in development server now). In a certain game there can easily be 10 judges, but if the games account for the thousands votes scale * =~10 * number of questions * number of players.
- I postpone the recount with a task queue. If every vote does the same: Are we not in the same case as the first point, only postponed ?

I have read about sharding counters, but I don't see them fit here; The votes are correctly cast, is just the "event" of passing the test which seems tricky to me.

Thanks very much for any insight or ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions should work here and will not be a problem in the future. They only "lock" the touched Entity Groups and won't avoid you to scale.

Your third point should work too, if you delay the launch of you taskqueues enough (I would say 3 to 5s). The datastore should be up to date during this check.

But nothing avoids you to try this 2 solutions together, just to be "sure".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'll go first for that taskqueue aproach as it doesn't imply contention and could therefore be more 'economic'